# Is this an appropriate place for discussion of individual Open Data tools?

Tags: discussion, site-scope

Even though I haven't been able to participate much I would really like to see this space succeed. I'm wondering if this space would be an appropriate space for discussion of open data tools.

Specifically we are thinking about driving users who have non-bug type questions about [DKAN](http://getdkan.com) to this site and monitoring any posts specifically tagged DKAN to provide answers. This seems like a good idea because it would hopefully drive users to participate and hopefully encourage discussion around other tools as well.

A "con" or risk of doing this would be that the site might feel monopolized by DKAN.

What do the mods think? Maybe if we directed other open data tools here as well it might mitigate that risk? Or maybe this is just not the place for what we were thinking above?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If these tools are a specific and integral part of the Open Data landscape, then almost certainly, **these questions should be on topic here.** I'm not talking about generalized software where the author just happens to be using it with Open Data… but specialized tools specifically designed for and used by this community.

As a matter of fact, the developers of these applications tend to have communities of their own, and these special interest groups have become a huge source of excellent questions and avid, supporting communities on a lot of sites. If these questions are being asked, **we should encourage them to become part of the ecosystem of *this* site.**

This is really no different than what we've done on Stack Overflow (and a lot of other sites) for quite awhile. Check out the top two answer in this thread for details.

[**Is it okay to use Stack Overflow as the support forum for a product or project?**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3966/is-it-okay-to-use-stack-overflow-as-the-support-forum-for-a-product-or-project)

We get a lot of requests from project teams about how they can use Stack Exchange to support their communities. I see no reason why *this* site couldn't provide fantastic ***technical*** support for end-user products used by Open Data users! This doesn't mean that companies should outsource their entire customer support channel here (e.g. no bug reports, feature requests, etc). Open Data SE should be but *one* support option for these products — community-driven technical support.

Comment: Thanks for this great response.

Comment: I think this "Where-to-post-summary" sums it up the best: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3974 .